# What do you call people who think the war is over after one battle is won?

Tags: single-word-requests

People who think that everything is fine even when it's not yet.

Example:

> Most white people don't pay much attention to the 'Black Lives Matter' movement because they think that "we fought that fight already, everything is fine now". But, clearly, they are blind, as black people still feel the war is not over.

(I know this is a hotly contested example  but it's the clearest one I could think of.)

The word I'm looking for is similar to hypocritical.

Comment: Have you looked up synonyms of *hypocritical*? Alternatively, you might want to consider *naive*.

Comment: Do you really need a single word?

Comment: It's unclear what sense you wish to convey -- prejudiced, non-perceptive, confirmation bias, etc.

Answer (score 3):

People who think the war is over when the battle is won are: **short-sighted**. They do not take a long view of social movements or situations. They only see what is right before their eyes.

Comment: myopic means short-sighted. As to the most white people, to hell with that, frankly. Who are you to say?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *complacent* or *blithe*.  Excerpts from vocabulary.com:

> [***blithe***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/blithe) - The adjective blithe used to mean happy and carefree, but over time it has also come to describe someone who isn't paying attention the way they should.
>
> [***complacent***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/complacent) - The literal meaning of this word's Latin root is "very pleased," but even though complacent people may seem pleased with themselves, we are rarely pleased with them. They are unconcerned by things that should concern them

Comment: -1 for blithe, +1 for complacent

Comment: Why not split them into two answers?

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrase "wishful thinkers" fits.

Answer (score 0):

How about *over-optimistic*?

Macmillan:

> [*over-optimistic*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/british/over-optimistic):
>   expecting things to happen in the future in a better way than most
>   people think is likely